# v8 JavaScript function execution hangs in Runtime_TryInstallOptimizedCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I have noticed a strange issue after upgrading the embedded V8 library from 3.28.4 to 6.1.534.47 (same as in current node.js 8.9.1). I have some code that dispatches events to JavaScript code (basically comes down to calling `v8::Function::Call()`). This runs fine thousands of times, but eventually `v8::Function::Call()` does not return, hanging in `v8::internal::Runtime_TryInstallOptimizedCode()`.

Here's a stack trace:

```
frame #0: 0x0000000104f43cfc libv8.dylib`v8::internal::Runtime_TryInstallOptimizedCode(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [inlined] v8::internal::__RT_impl_Runtime_TryInstallOptimizedCode(v8::internal::Arguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) at runtime-compiler.cc:374 [opt]
frame #1: 0x0000000104f43cd5 libv8.dylib`v8::internal::Runtime_TryInstallOptimizedCode(args_length=1, args_object=0x0000700001d1a0f0, isolate=0x000000010182d200) at runtime-compiler.cc:371 [opt]
frame #2: 0x000028715ea040bd
frame #3: 0x000028715ea15b12
frame #4: 0x000028715ea12cf0
frame #5: 0x000028715eadea2d
frame #6: 0x0000000104cb5ba3 libv8.dylib`v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::Invoke(isolate=0x000000010182d2c8, is_construct=<unavailable>, target=<unavailable>, receiver=<unavailable>, argc=1, args=0x0000700001d1ad10, new_target=<unavailable>, message_handling=<unavailable>) at execution.cc:145 [opt]
frame #7: 0x0000000104cb58cc libv8.dylib`v8::internal::Execution::Call(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*) [inlined] v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::CallInternal(message_handling=kReport) at execution.cc:181 [opt]
frame #8: 0x0000000104cb585d libv8.dylib`v8::internal::Execution::Call(isolate=0x000000010182d200, callable=Handle<v8::internal::Object> @ r12, receiver=<unavailable>, argc=1, argv=0x0000700001d1ad10) at execution.cc:191 [opt]
frame #9: 0x0000000104984d80 libv8.dylib`v8::Function::Call(this=0x000000010281fa50, context=<unavailable>, recv=<unavailable>, argc=1, argv=0x0000700001d1ad10) at api.cc:5343 [opt]
frame #10: 0x0000000104849c01 libPocoJSCored.1.dylib`Poco::JS::Core::JSExecutor::callInContext(this=0x0000000102029a00, jsObject=0x0000000100e64458, method="valueChanged", argc=1, argv=0x0000700
```

Observed this on both macOS 10.12 with Clang/Apple LLVM 9.0 and Ubuntu 17.10 with GCC 7.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

V8 developer here. Please file a bug on [bugs.chromium.org/p/v8](http://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8).

Are you doing anything funky with threads?

Do you have a repro you can share?

If you run with --trace-opt, what are the last lines of output before it hangs?

Can you compile in Debug mode and run in a debugger to see where exactly it hangs? (An obvious guess would be waiting for `output_queue_mutex_` in `OptimizingCompileDispatcher::InstallOptimizedFunctions()`, but I don't see how a deadlock on that mutex could happen, so before barking up the wrong tree, it would be nice to be sure what precisely the issue is.)

Comment: Thanks. Got distracted with other issues in the meantime, but will file a bug report with more information today.

Comment: To follow up here: this bug is already fixed on later V8 versions (6.4+), see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6933. For 6.2/6.3, you can cherry-pick the fix yourself, e.g. Node is doing that here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/17695